# How can I tell if RestKit v0.20.2 served a result from the entity cache?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a core data mapped object managed by Restkit and am able to fetch JSON from my web service using

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:jobRequest parameters:nil
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)`

which works beautifully. If I request the same object more than once, it isn't creating a new managed object if it exists in the `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache`.

My question though, is how can I tell if the object was already in the cache? I would like to display an 'up to date' style message to the user if they already have the item - I can query this manually against my core objects but is this something that is exposed by RestKit (perhaps in the `RKMappingResult` parameter of the `success` block)?

Comment: Knowing that you already have the object doesn't necessarily mean that it's up-to-date though does it? If so, you don't need to make the network request...

Comment: The object will only exist once, so if I have it it is up to date. I don't know if I have it yet though as the server will return one or more objects for a request. For example, a code is submitted to a service to return a daily task, or multiple tasks. Client side I can't decipher the code so can't tell which objects should be returned (or whether I have them already). I can't modify the webservice to expire these codes either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use Core Data to determine what's new. You can observe changes to the managed object context and it will give you sets of inserted, updated and deleted objects.